# How to get the endianness when reading a message from socket?

Tags: sockets, networking, encoding, go, protocol-buffers

I am using `go` and `protocol buffers`. `go` program sends encoded protocol buffer messages to clients connected to the socket. Now since protocol-buffers is not delimited, clients don't know how much data to read from the socket.

I am planning to prefix the message with the message length, a 32bit integer. So clients can read 4 bytes, get the length and read the full message.

I can put an integer value into the bytes array using `binary` package. Something like,

```
binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, value)
```

Now the question is, `write` needs a byte order and how will the receiving end know what is the byte order? Is there a way to deal with this without specifying explicit byte order?

Answer (score 6):

The convention is that [network byte order is big endian](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700), but your client and server must agree in any case. Specify the byte order explicitly.

Edit: Reading the Protobuf docs, it might be better to use [`proto.EncodeVarint`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto#EncodeVarint) and [`proto.DecodeVarint`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto#DecodeVarint) to write the length before the message, for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 2):

You should **always** explicitly define and document the byte order (and layout) on such things. In general communications, big-endian direct layout seems to be the norm (so 47 would be 4 bytes with hex values 00 00 00 2F). However, you might want to take specific context into consideration. For example, if you are *already* talking protobuf, you could also use the "varint" encoding format, in which case 47 is a single byte: 2F - many protobuf implementations will provide pre-rolled methods to consume or produce a varint (otherwise, it is [documented here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints) - but can be summarised as 7-bit payload with continuation bit, with the least-significant 7-bit group first)

Comment: Thanks. `varint` makes sense.. Will see if the Java API supports a method to produce & consume varint

Comment: Looks like I can use `CodedInputStream#readRawVarint32()` for this.

Comment: What do you think about this: Read each byte at a time, asking protobuf to parse it and if it fails, keep reading and parsing until it passes. This way we don't need length to be prefixed. Do you think this is a better approach than prefixing length?

Comment: @Appu that is not valid; a protobuf stream is not terminated (they are designed to be appendable). As such, you cannot determine where a payload ends. If you do what you propose, you will only read the first field of the message. The second field would be interpreted as a second message. Basically, "no, you cannot do that".